# I can't find my docker container running on specified host

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a simple react app, which shows compile when I run the following command docker run -p 8080:8080 anirudh9654/startup:1
But I can't see it running in my localhost:8080

This is my DockerFile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent


# add app
COPY . ./

EXPOSE 8080

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What have you tried to do to troubleshoot so far?

Comment: Try to replace npm with yarn

Comment: So your react app was created with `create-react-app`? I think the default port for this app would be 3000. When you start your react app outside of docker, which port is used?  This would then also be the port to expose.